# weak star convergent net is uniformly convergent on weakly compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^\ast$ its (topological)dual space.

Let $x_\alpha^\ast,x^\ast\in B_{X^\ast}$, where $B_{X^\ast}$ denotes the closed unit ball of $X^\ast$, such that $x_\alpha^\ast\to x^\ast$ in the weak star topology, and $A\subset X$ is weakly compact. Does $x_\alpha^\ast$ converge to $x^\ast$ uniformly on $A$?

Under what condition(s) could this statement be true?

Comment: what does uniform convergence mean in this situation?

Comment: @colossal I mean for given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\alpha_0$ such that $|x_\alpha^*x-x^*x|< \epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $\alpha\geq \alpha_0$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Zim In the case that $A$ is compact I proved the problem. For $\epsilon>0$ given, let $A\subset \cup_1^n B(x_i, \epsilon)$ then for any $x\in A$ there exists some $x_i$ such that $\|x-x_i\|<\epsilon$. So $|x_\alpha^*x-x^*x|\leq |(x_\alpha^*-x^*)(x-x_i)|+|(x_\alpha^*-x^*)x_i|$. the second term is less than $\epsilon$ from a $\alpha_0$ now on and the first term is less than $(\|x_\alpha^*\|+\|x^*\|)\|x-x_i\|<2\epsilon$. But for the case that $A$ is weakly compact I didn't know how to begin. Do you have a proof? is it true for weakly compact sets at all?

Comment: Are we to also assume that $x_a^*$ resides in $A$ then?

Comment: @Zim what do you mean by "$x_\alpha^*$ resides in $A$"?

Comment: Are you assuming that $x_a^*\in A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no in general.  If $X$ is reflexive, then $B_X$ is weakly compact and clearly $x_\alpha^*\to x^\star$ uniformly on $A=B_X$ iff the convergence is in norm.

Comment: I should add that, in view of Arzela-Ascoli, the answer is yes provided the given sequence is equi-continuous.  However, every equi-continuous set for the weak topology must be contained in a finite dimensional space, so the application of Arzela-Ascoli here becomes very limited.

Comment: thanks for the explanation -- I have never heard of equi-continuity before; do you have a recommended book for reading up on this?

Comment: @Zim, check out Rudin's books. Or else Kelley (general topology) or Engelking (ditto). Royden and Conway also treat it IIRC.